# Looping through all the form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have the following code where I am able to loop through all my form fields but the value is getting saved only for the first one and due to this the console shows 7 iterations of the first form field value only.On the other hand I want it to come one by one for all the form fields so that I can validate them.   Thanks in advance.

```
$('formsection[name="AUDIT REPORT"]').find('input,select').each(function() {
  hi = [];
  hi = $('formsection[name="AUDIT REPORT"]').find('input,select').val();
  console.log(hi);

});
```

Comment: Use `$(this).val()`.

Comment: Typo there? `form section`? Use `:input` selector.

Comment: I dont think it was a typo but thanks a lot dude it worked. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly note there should be a space between `form` and `section` in the selector, as `formsection` isn't a valid HTML element.

The issue itself is due to the use of the same selector within the `each()` handler function. As the resulting jQuery object contains a collection of Elements then calling `val()` will only read from the first element of the set. It does not return an array as you seem to be expecting.

To fix this, use the `this` keyword to refer to the current element in the iteration:

```
$('form section[name="AUDIT REPORT"]').find('input,select').each(function() {
  var hi = $(this).val();
  console.log(hi);
});
```

Also note that the `:input` selector could also meet your needs without the use of `find()`:

```
$('form section[name="AUDIT REPORT"] :input').each(function() {
  var hi = $(this).val();
  console.log(hi);
});
```

Comment: We think similarly :)

Comment: Thankyou @Rory McCrossan.A very well explained answer always helps.

Comment: @SHIKHARSINGH no problem, glad to help